# Facebook API Public Friends of A USERID

Tags: python, django, facebook, web-services, facebook-graph-api

I am making a web service using django python. I am able to get my friends information when I logged in. I want to know the steps or an API in which if I pass a userId it will give me list of his/her public friends

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid access_token and a Graph API call to `/me/friends`

The API documentation for this is listed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends

Not sure which Django module you are using or whether there is a stable one out there but the following is in facepy github.com/jgorset/facepy

```
import web
from facepy import GraphAPI
from urlparse import parse_qs

url = ('/', 'index')

app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID"
app_secret = "APP_SECRET"
post_login_url = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/"

class index:
    def GET(self):
        user_data = web.input(code=None)
        code = user_data.code

if not user_data.code:
    dialog_url = ( "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" +
                               "client_id=" + app_id +
                               "&redirect_uri=" + post_login_url )

    return "<script>top.location.href='" + dialog_url + "'</script>"
else:
    graph = GraphAPI()
    response = graph.get(
        path='oauth/access_token',
        client_id=app_id,
        client_secret=app_secret,
        redirect_uri=post_login_url,
        code=code
    )
    data = parse_qs(response)
    graph = GraphAPI(data['access_token'][0])
    friends_data = graph.get('me/friends')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(url, globals())
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/facebook-sdk ?
Seems like it might do what you are looking for.